# Edit before or after original post?

Tags: discussion, edits

I have noticed that when a user edits his question / answer after a long period of time of its original writing in order to add new research etc that using add a new section entitled 'Edit' (usually in bold)

Should this section be added before or after the original post?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless it is absolutely necessary, it is best if you try to organically integrate the new information directly into the post (rewrite the entire post if needed).  It is not necessary to keep all of the original post if it is not relevant, as the edit history will show what you original wrote (unless you are editing within the 5 minute grace period).

Posts that have long edit histories still in the post with **Edit**, **Edit 2**, **Edit 3**, etc are very difficult to read, and should be avoided.

**One additional note for questions.**
When editing questions, it is important you do not invalidate existing answers.  It is a very fine line between clarifying your question and changing the question and you need to be careful not to cross it, especially if your question has answers.

The reason for this is that people have taken the time to answer your question and if you change the question, you could unintentionally open them up to downvotes from people who do not read the edit history and think they are not answering the question correctly.

For more info on this, please see [Doesn't the asker have the right to modify his question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167070/doesnt-the-asker-have-the-right-to-modify-his-question) and the 2 top voted answers answers (full disclosure, one of the answers is mine but both have valuable info)

Comment: For answers, this is solid advice. For questions, be careful not to invalidate any existing answers. A good tradeoff is to integrate the new information, but to leave a note about what the old information was, if answers depend on it.